# CKEditor in asp.net, in ajax tab, toolbar does not show up

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010, ckeditor

I am trying to use CKEditor in a Ajax Tab, but the toolbar doesn't show up

I added this to Web.config `<add tagPrefix="CKEditor" assembly="CKEditor.NET" namespace="CKEditor.NET"/>`

and this `<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorControl1" runat="server" Toolbar=""></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>` into my webpage.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: @Govind there was nothing mentioned about that in the instructions, how do we do that?

Comment: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Beginners

Comment: @Govind still doesn't work, I am using visual studio 2010, this example is in 2008, I wonder if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add ckeditor folder which contains actual editor files(js files etc.) to your website directory.

Answer (score 0):

Drop property Toolbar="" or modify to Toolbar="Basic".